# How can we link freetype library to Embedded Projects?

Tags: fonts, freetype, keil, coocox

I am a newbie to freetype and embedded system too. 
I want to use freetype functions in my embedded application (Details are given below).

At first i tried the instructions given in "http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html".

I could successfully complete a c project as in "example1.c" (given in freetype tutorial) in ubuntu, which can display the raster image created by the freetype .

But  I don't know how to link freetype library to keil ide or coocox ide.

I have freetype 2.5.5 source as in http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.5.5.tar.gz

I added the include directory to coocox include directory. But it created error "undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType' " etc.

I tried copying "libfreetype.so" file from ubuntu and linked it  in the coocox project. Also made include path to freetype include directory. The header files are included.But it cannot identify the library.

Now I guess the library files are different for different toolchain. I read the documentation in the downloaded source. Unfortunately didn't understand how to create library file for arm toolchain.

Can you please explain the way to link freetype to either keil or Coocox ide?

Project Details:
Controller : LPC1768
IDE : Keil uvision 4, uvision 5 or CoIDE 1.3.1
everyone

Thank you,

Tintu Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution. It is freetype amalgamate project. I think it is better than a library. Here all the source files are amalgamated.

Here is the link [freetype amalgamate](https://github.com/vinniefalco/FreeTypeAmalgam)